# Mocking programs

Tags: linux

I'm looking for ways to "disable" commands, so instead of running the original program I'd like to run *nothing* instead.

I got some ways to do that, but the most effective way so far is creating a new script with the same name and change the `PATH` environment variable prioritizing the new mock script to run.

**Mocking it with another script by PATH:** Consider a command called `mycmd`, which we are going to mock it "exiting 0" (and ignoring all the input arguments):

```bsh
mkdir -p ~/tmp/mockscript
echo -e "#!/usr/bin/bash\nexit 0\n" > ~/tmp/mockscript/mycmd
chmod +x ~/tmp/mockscript/mycmd
PATH=~/tmp/mockscript:$PATH
```

We can do something similar with `alias` but it has to be defined each time a new shell is opened, instead of being mocked only once, like the trick with PATH variable.

Is there any better way to do that? What?

Comment: Do you want to mock *all* programs or just some? Mocking all programs doesn't make much sense and you can achieve that with `set -n`. You're looking for a dry-run mode, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2012-11/msg00010.html

Comment: See _realias_ example at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/582877/49368

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, not all programs, but just one (or some).

Comment: @K7AAY "alias" is one of the options I said in the question. And its main disadvantage is that it needs to be done for all bash instances, so in a kind of .bashrc (.profile) files, that imposes some usage restrictions.